# Load gallery thumbnails async with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, asynchronous

I am using TN3 gallery in a WP Website (Not the WP plugin but the jQuery library).

In the gallery, the large images load when you need them and that's great as the page load does not block. But the thumbnails are loaded all (even the ones that are not visible) and the page is stuck until all of them are loaded.

```
$images = get_field('gallery_images');
if( $images ): ?>
  <div id="" class="mygallery">
    <ol class="">
      <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

        <li>
          <?php if($image[$captionKey]): ?>
            <div class="tn3 description"><?php echo $image[$captionKey]; ?></div>
          <?php endif; ?>                        

          <a href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image['id'], 'gallery-thumb' ); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there away I can make the thumbnails load in the background without blocking the rest of the page?

Comment: Images are always loaded asynchronously by the browser. What exactly does "stuck" mean? Are you trying to execute JavaScript?

Comment: @elusive Hi you can look here http://heseg.com/gallery/פורים-2012-בהישג/?lang=he , The rest of the page is not loaded (Galleries Navigation) until the thumbnails are loaded.

Comment: So you want to influence the order that the browser loads the images in?

Comment: @elusive Yes that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

As variant you can insert into thumbnails 1px image and add some attribute with real thumbnail src. After page ready in jQuery event replace all thumbnails src with that attribute value.